# Table row padding not disappearing

Tags: html, css

I am having a little problem with my padding in a table. I created a table and I noticed that my rows have a lot of empty text.

Thus I tried to put the padding and margin to zero but this hasn't helped to reduce the big white gap at all.

I have joined a picture of what I would like to be taken off.

If anyone has any suggestions that could help get rid of this problem and thus make the table more compact.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/u39fqw38/

Unfortunately I can't post the html here as it has to many Chinese characters and this is blocked by the SO filters.

```
tr{
  height:10;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
td{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `height:10;` is invalid as it does not contain units.

To fix your problem, you can add:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Fixed [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u39fqw38/1/).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot i think i forgot the border-collapse and that's why it wasn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the padding is coming from the `<p>` elements.